# Minimize Pagination Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, pagination

I have a pagination and it looks like this: < 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 >

[image]

But it's too big, so I need to display them like this: < 1 2 3 4 ... 21>

This is my template:

```js
ul.pagination.float-right
            li.page-item
              a.page-link(v-on:click="prevPage()")
                i.icon.ion-ios-arrow-back
            li(v-for="n in numberOfPages")
              a.page-link(@click="goToPage(n)", :limit="3" :style= "[actualPage == n && {backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3'}]") {{n}}
            li.page-item
              a.page-link(v-on:click="nextPage()")
                i.icon.ion-ios-arrow-forward
```

and my script:

```js
data () {
    return {
      numberOfPages: 0,
      roles: [],
      rolesInPage: [],
      actualPage: 1,
      elementsByPage: 10,
```

```js
    prevPage () {
      if (this.actualPage > 1) {
        this.actualPage = this.actualPage - 1
      }
      const from = this.elementsByPage * (this.actualPage - 1)
      this.rolesInPage = this.roles.slice(from, from + 10)
    },
    nextPage () {
      if (this.actualPage < this.numberOfPages) {
        this.actualPage = this.actualPage + 1
      }
      const from = this.elementsByPage * (this.actualPage - 1)
      this.rolesInPage = this.roles.slice(from, from + 10)
    },
    getNumberOfPages () {
      return Math.ceil(this.roles.length / this.elementsByPage)
    },
    goToPage (page) {
      this.actualPage = page
      const from = this.elementsByPage * (this.actualPage - 1)
      this.rolesInPage = this.roles.slice(from, from + this.elementsByPage)
    },
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a basic solution, but needs some improvements and you'll need to validate in your frontend what's the limit of pages to show and place those dots between them.

[The basic solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUHsFsFNWpAxgawM4CgA2sAuoBDJXAVwKwAUCBzeAXlAEYBubPUWHOAO1zQCEAnlVqgGjAAysc+biWgAjWACcA8gDMRsNGNBS2+ZZBxoAkty26A2gF1p7IyYBcoOYpW3rEgDRNfAJl8AZl8AFl8AVl8ANl8Adl8ADl8ATl9JdMZ0wKYQpnCmKKZYpgSmZKY00H8faqzqnP88-wL-Iv8S-zL-Cv8qoNqg+qCcoLyggqCioJKgsqCKoKrQ2tD60JzQvNCC0KLQktCy0IrQqoiJOwwMEFAAKRI0fEFIEmVQJEgAE1gMT+4nqAAA7KWAAN0sDAAFABKMQAPlAAG8MKA0eiAJbqUBQoikciWRGMOEo9FkwjEMiUGj0Cn46miAC0TFR5IAvqyyf9AeojNBdJxYDw+EJLAAqHF4qmWZnEznoxzacyQ0CKtAAOjQWAxSFgUN5MF8Bv5AGomBIYRg2aw-pAAbJYAAPXAq2EI5HytFYyWUgk00AAHlc8iUak0NLQJM96KlftEDFjDPgZsY0Y55I+dp5fIFXFgvAEwn9EtxvqToFllozauV-oYas12t1+r5RpzKYtVpt3PwtFwADkQyoNFodNC4XREaTyaDSMpuKAALIEXAAC3VuoxWChDZw3Goa9AYEFwsLWkt1uuPdA1EgABVIK6gTSXG5QxOp9HEyrn7Ro9fjVzIV8xFItRBLb9-UraMawsOtVWMbRGx1PVjTbGBQDNE8QLPGkL1YW4HkBF43kzH5rluABhUEV3gAgFwIZRlAIQRQAAdwxQ813gN8VB0SBsSMNidAxBcSPeXACAUHBQEgd56MENdROoG4wHor5VTwN4F244N3HeATgQjUBcEgUA0FXSA2MIbgNN0rACEBX9YHVVTQAATVeAByLAsFcWBYDsszoAIFB4DQGB4CwSBqB1EyzJ+ch2M41cTNXDERJ01d4ANXh8y+W17U0uduEHfSRwjB9TFwFRaN0N1Jw9MkZHMyzlFwABBJiWI0MrR2sK4uSzfBtWgTjdCCG0yXUOScRajFdBYUAFoDBg+zK0MKtoNBYWYZaTRNKMMzRCy5M67rBF6+RR3VIFHlXKEMRhVgyXTdF5WvNxRyqmrmJq3RTvarrmMu9Q+ojZDm0gpk-FAUbxrNUt6RlJgYWe+UvsqyBqtqmrbvuqF1qHMNR1hdH5VnbS9O+7Hfto1gOUKiKcHVaLqB3LT5w24dw22n7cb1NHmCAA)

That function returns an array with just the indexes you want and an extra index with the total of pages you already had.